# Cargo conditional dependency feature

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to include features of a dependencies dependent on the activation of the feature in my library. If I compile with feature `"serde"`, I want to install `ndarray` with `"serde"` support. And the default should be the default `ndarray` install.

I' want something like this `Cargo.toml`

```
[features]
include-serde = ["ndarray-with-serde"]

[dependencies]
ndarray = { version = "0.x" }
ndarray-with-serde = { version = "0.x", features=["serde"] }
```

Is this possible at the moment?

Answer (score 3):

You can add the features of a crate after a `/`.

```
[features]
myfeature = ["library_foo/bar", "libary_foo/ham"]

[dependencies]
library_foo = { version = "0.x" }
```

The snippet above install features `"bar"` and `"ham"` from `"library_foo"` when `"myfeature"` is activated.